# download related to pdf

Tags: pdf, printing

How can I download this file in which  you can view it but you can't download , print or copy.

http://shodhbhagirathi.iitr.ac.in:8081/jspui/image/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=/jspui/bitstream/123456789/7469/1/CED%20G11729.pdf

Comment: `you can view it but you can't` ... you either can view something,  or you cannot view something  ... you cannot do both

Comment: It looks like its using a web based viewer, and that has, but blocks the download/print/copy and so on buttons

Comment: jsotola actually i can only view thats how they protect this file .you can also visit this site then you know it.